# In R, x and y are arrays (time series data), how to calculate cor() for trend correlation?

Tags: r, time-series

I want to see the correlation of two time series datasets.

```r
df <- data.frame(
    row.names = paste0("s", 1:5),
    R_T1 = 1:5, R_T2 = 2:6, R_T3 = 3:7,
    P_T1 = 4:8, P_T2 = 5:9, P_T4 = 6:10
)
```

That looks like Table 1

```
   R_T1 R_T2 R_T3 P_T1 P_T2 P_T4
s1    1    2    3    4    5    6
s2    2    3    4    5    6    7
s3    3    4    5    6    7    8
s4    4    5    6    7    8    9
s5    5    6    7    8    9   10
```

or Table 2

```
       R   P
s1 T1  1   4    
s1 T2  2   5    
s1 T3  3   6  
s2 T1  2   5    
s2 T2  3   6    
s2 T3  4   7
```

s1-s5 are samples names; R and P are two variables, each variable has 3 observation results.
What I want to calculate is `cor(c(R_T1,R_T2,R_T3), c(P_T1,P_T2,P_T3))` for each sample.
For example: for s1, `cor(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))` but not `cor(R_T1,P_T1)`, `cor(R_T2,P_T2)`...is the second table more clear?
The purpose is to calculate the trend correlation of R and P.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** The question indicates you want the correlation between R and P for each sample so we are looking for 5 correlations corresponding to the 5 samples. Create two data frames each of which has one column per sample with rows corresponding to time.  Then use mapply to get the correlations of the first column of R with the first column of P, the second column of R with the second column of P, etc.

```
isR <- startsWith(names(df), "R")
R <- as.data.frame(t(df[isR]))
P <- as.data.frame(t(df[!isR]))
mapply(cor, R, P)
## s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 
##  1  1  1  1  1
```

**2)** It could also be written like this:

```
spl <- split(as.data.frame(t(df)), startsWith(names(df), "R"))
do.call("mapply", c(cor, unname(spl)))
## s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 
##  1  1  1  1  1
```

**3)** or using pipes:

```
df |>
  t() |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  list(. = _) |>
  with(split(., startsWith(rownames(.), "R"))) |>
  unname() |>
  c(FUN = cor) |>
  do.call(what = "mapply")
```

Comment: Hi @G. Grothendieck, thanks very much for your answer. What I want to calculate is cor(x, y) for each sample (s1, s2,....), and x=c(R_T1,R_T2,R_T3), y=c(P_T1,P_T2,P_T3) but not x=df$R_T1, y=df$P_T1 and summerising all sample together.

Comment: Yes, I know.  It does NOT calculate the correlation of df$R_T1 and DF$P_T1.   It calculates the 5 correlations (1) the correlation of df[1, 1:3] with df[1, 4:6], (2) the correlation of df[2, 1:3]  with df[2, 4:6], ..., (5) the correlation of df[5, 1:3] with df[5, 4:6].

Comment: yes, you are right. Your method fits Table1 format. I found another way to do when using Table2. df  %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(correlation = cor(var1, var2, method = "sp")).

Answer (score 0):

First of all hi!

Initially, I wanted to tell you that this is not the proper way to present your data neither your question!

If I understood your data structure this should be like the following,

```
df<-structure(list(R_T1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
               R_T2 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
               R_T3 = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
               P_T1 = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
               P_T2 = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
               P_T3 = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)),
          row.names = c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5"),
          class = "data.frame")
```

Then (again if I understood correctly), you want the correlation of R vs. P for each time point!

```
CorrelationT1 <- cor(df$R_T1,df$P_T1)
CorrelationT2 <- cor(df$R_T2,df$P_T2)
CorrelationT3 <- cor(df$R_T3,df$P_T3)
```

The problem here is that your data are highly correlated, so just to give you a more random data to check, please see bellow,

```
dfrnorm<-structure(list(R_T1 = rnorm(5),
               R_T2 = rnorm(5),
               R_T3 = rnorm(5),
               P_T1 = rnorm(5),
               P_T2 = rnorm(5),
               P_T3 = rnorm(5)),
          row.names = c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5"),
          class = "data.frame")
```

With the respected correlations,

```
CorrelationT1 <- cor(dfrnorm$R_T1,dfrnorm$P_T1)
CorrelationT2 <- cor(dfrnorm$R_T2,dfrnorm$P_T2)
CorrelationT3 <- cor(dfrnorm$R_T3,dfrnorm$P_T3)
```

And a simple plot could be like this,

```
plot(1:3,
     c(CorrelationT1,CorrelationT2,CorrelationT3),
     xlab="Time Points", ylab="Correlation")
```

I hope this will help you,

Cheers

Comment: Caveat: Time series data is often highly correlated due to autocorrelation (previous values affect future values).  If this can be an issue for you, you need to control for the effect appropriately.

Comment: Hi @Antreas, first of all, I would much appreciated your answers. I am new to stack overflow and this is my first question. Please forgive my unclear expression. What I want to calculate is cor(x, y) for each sample (s1, s2,....), and x=c(R_T1,R_T2,R_T3), y=c(P_T1,P_T2,P_T3) but not x=df$R_T1, y=df$P_T1 and summerising all sample together.